# Namespace conflicts

Tags: c#, namespaces

Ive got a project that uses the Google .NET API.

It has a root namespace of 'Google' (unsuprisingly).

Ive just created a class with the following namespace

```
namespace Foo.Google{    
class Bar{ }
}
```

Obviously this is now going to 'conflict' as `Google` is ambiguous (precedence is actually given to `Foo.Google`).

Other than just renaming `Foo.Google` to `Foo.Goog`, are then any other cleverer approaches?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there are no cleverer approaches. Avoiding namespaces conflicts by not using the same namespaces of the third party code which you use is the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

Try `global::Google.Whatever`.

Answer (score 2):

You can import the Google .NET API using an alias (check reference properties).

Answer (score 0):

(If I've understood the question correctly) cant you do something like:

```
using GoogleApi = Google;
```